# Using navigator.platform to detect os in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, navigator

I'm trying to detect browser version on the client side using navigator.platform.  I can't find a list of all the platform identifiers.  I've looked at w3C, the MDN documentation, and googled it. (I even resorted to Bing...) Could you point me to a list?

Thank you,

Comment: I guess `navigator.platform` is not very detailed, maybe you can try the `userAgent` string.

Comment: Something lighter than a library: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: wait, browser version or OS ?

Answer (score 1):

Reliably checking the platform information isn't an easy problem. You can parse out `navigator.userAgent`, but I'd recommend using a library that can do this for you. [Platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js) looks to be the most featured of these libraries.